# Jquery MultiZoom Plugin not loading at Page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with jQuery multizoom plugin. `document.ready()` and `window.load()` won't start it on the main function. on page load

- div (#slide_body) slides out from left to right.
- then inside this div(#slide_body) I am calling jQuery plugin Multizoom on PIctures.
- Because of slide_body jQuery multizoom is not loading. I have tried `document.read()` or `window.load()` but the plugin wont start.
- if I resize the webpage (Ctrl + mouse wheel) then it starts working, as it repositions the page elements.
- or if I click a thumb Image then it starts working. But first image never works on Page Load.

Please guide how to load this first time when the page loads. any other event to try apart from Document.ready() or window.load()

Thanks

```
<script>
function slid_body(){
    document.getElementById('slid_body').style.left = "0px";
    //document.getElementById('slid_body').style.width = "804px";
}
function slideIn() {
    //document.getElementById('slid_body').style.left = "0px";

    document.getElementById('slid_body').style.left = "-804px";
}
</script>
<body onload="javascript:slid_body()">   
 <div id="slid_body_out">
            <div id="slid_body">
                <div id="heading">
                    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
                        <li>Collection</li>
                        <li>
                            Casual</li>
                      </ul>
                <div id="left">
                    <div id="prodetail">
                        <div id="pro_dtl_left">
                            <div id="pro_dtl_leftimg">

                                <div class='targetarea'><img id='multizoom1' src='images/ProductImages/Medium/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' alt='zoomable'L32840'></img></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="pro_dtl_right_moreviews">
                                <p>
                                    Scroll on above image to view enlarged picture<br />
                                    Use Mouse Scroll to Zoom in/out.
                                </p>
                                <li>More Views</li>
                                <br />
                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_litThumbs" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;"><ul><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li></ul></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                $('#multizoom1').addimagezoom({
                    descArea: '#description',
                    speed: 1000,
                    descpos: true,
                    imagevertcenter: true,
                    magvertcenter: true,
                    zoomrange: [3, 10],
                    magnifiersize: [500, 450],
                    magnifierpos: right,
                    cursorshadecolor: '#5C2E91',
                    cursorshade: true
                });

            })

        </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe is the `body onload="javascript:slid_body()"` who collides with the `$(document).ready` jQuery function.

Try this, that keeps the script on one place:

```
<body>   
 <div id="slid_body_out">
            <div id="slid_body">
                <div id="heading">
                    <ul id="breadcrumbs">
                        <li>Collection</li>
                        <li>
                            Casual</li>
                      </ul>
                <div id="left">
                    <div id="prodetail">
                        <div id="pro_dtl_left">
                            <div id="pro_dtl_leftimg">

                                <div class='targetarea'><img id='multizoom1' src='images/ProductImages/Medium/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' alt='zoomable'L32840'></img></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="pro_dtl_right_moreviews">
                                <p>
                                    Scroll on above image to view enlarged picture<br />
                                    Use Mouse Scroll to Zoom in/out.
                                </p>
                                <li>More Views</li>
                                <br />
                                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_litThumbs" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;"><ul><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634981200372366040_XGN_6539.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982980662846576_XGN_6537.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982981340675266_XGN_6540.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li><li class='multizoom1 thumbs'><a href='images/ProductImages/Medium/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG'  data-large='images/ProductImages/Original/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG' data-title='L32840'><img src='images/ProductImages/thumb/634982981855793870_XGN_6538.JPG' alt='L32840' /></a></li></ul></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#multizoom1').addimagezoom({
                    descArea: '#description',
                    speed: 1000,
                    descpos: true,
                    imagevertcenter: true,
                    magvertcenter: true,
                    zoomrange: [3, 10],
                    magnifiersize: [500, 450],
                    magnifierpos: right,
                    cursorshadecolor: '#5C2E91',
                    cursorshade: true
                });

                function slid_body(){
                     document.getElementById('slid_body').style.left = "0px";
                }
                function slideIn() {    
                     document.getElementById('slid_body').style.left = "-804px";
                }

                slid_body();
            })

        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi.. Image Zoomer is fine this way.. but the sliding of the div is stopped.. Any Idea Why?